# Expected 2 arguments but got 1 - but I want to pass just one

Tags: javascript, typescript

I created a function with this signature:

```
  const createSomething = (
    someRange: number[],
    { option }: { option?: boolean }
  ) =>...
```

Sometimes I pass to the function just the `someRange` argument, and sometime the additional object argument. However I receive an error that the function expects two arguments. How can I declare the second argument to be optional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite odd that you can't do:

```
const createSomething = (
    someRange: number[],
    { option }?: { option?: boolean } // INVALID
) => {}
```

so you have to do:

```
const createSomething = (
    someRange: number[],
    { option }: { option?: boolean } = {}
) => {}
```

but then when you hover over `createSomething`, it shows the signature as the former???

[image: odd behavior]

Anyways, yeah, you can use a default value to show that it's optional.

---

In hindsight, it's quite obvious why it's invalid. If the second parameter is `undefined`, then you can't destructure it.

Answer (score 1):

Give your options object a default value `{}`, you can also give the `option` property a default value as well:

```
const createSomething = (
    someRange: number[],
    { option = false }: { option?: boolean } = {}
) => {
    console.log(option);
};

createSomething([1]); // Compiles and displays false
```